# Conditions for Routing in PHP

Tags: php, controller, twig

How do I make a condition the if the country is US the setViewFileName will use Which_Online_Shopper_Are_You_US/default.html.twig

```
public function routeWhich_Online_Shopper_Are_You(Get $request, Twig $response): array
{
    global $CONFIG;

    if (I18l::getCountryByDomain() !== "GB") {
        $response->redirect('/');
    }

    $siteName = $CONFIG['site_name'];
    $siteUrl  = $CONFIG['site_url'];

    $context = [
        'siteName' => $siteName,
        'siteUrl'  => $siteUrl
    ];

    $page = $this->project->config->getPage();
    $response->setViewFilename('Which_Online_Shopper_Are_You/default.html.twig');
    $page->setPageTitle('Which Online Shopper Are You');
    $page->updateMeta();

    return $context;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the view as a variable which you can overwrite depending on the current country.

I also made sure the US isn't redirected.

More details are added as comments in the code below:

```
public function routeWhich_Online_Shopper_Are_You(Get $request, Twig $response): array
{
    global $CONFIG;

    // Add all the allowed countries
    $allowed = ['GB', 'US'];

    // Get the current country
    $currentCountry = I18l::getCountryByDomain();

    // Check if the current country is in the allowed array. If not, redirect
    if (in_array($currentCountry, $allowed) === false) {
        $response->redirect('/');
    }

    // Set the default view
    $viewFile = 'Which_Online_Shopper_Are_You/default.html.twig';

    // Now override the view if the country is US
    if ($currentCountry === 'US') {
        $viewFile = 'Which_Online_Shopper_Are_You_US/default.html.twig';
    }

    $siteName = $CONFIG['site_name'];
    $siteUrl  = $CONFIG['site_url'];

    $context = [
        'siteName' => $siteName,
        'siteUrl'  => $siteUrl
    ];

    $page = $this->project->config->getPage();

    // Let's use our dynamic viewFile variable to set the view
    $response->setViewFilename($viewFile);
    
    $page->setPageTitle('Which Online Shopper Are You');
    $page->updateMeta();

    return $context;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir, the code posted is for the if the user is not using the .co.uk site it will redirect them to the homepage. What I'm to do is add a page for the .com site but still retain the GB page.Should I put the variable below the global $CONFIG;? Sorry this is all new to me. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: @NoobieSaibot - Now I've used your code as a base so you can see where and how it would be implemented. Basically, I've added so it doesn't redirect on neither US or GB but is setting a different view if it is US.

Comment: @NoobieSaibot - Does it make sense?

Comment: @NoobieSaibot - Please accept the answer so everyone knows it's been resolve.